# jQuery blur() event not working in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I want my img to blur when the user hovers over my one link but nothing happens. I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8", lang="en">
<title>Tsunamictech Limited</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myCSS1.css"/>
<script>
$("img").css({
                        'filter': blur(0px),
                        '-webkit-filter': blur(0px),
                        '-moz-filter': blur(0px),
                        '-o-filter': blur(0px),
                        '-ms-filter': blur(0px)
                    });
</script>
```

I have only a small working knowledge with JQuery (still learning web dev)... but I tried using the .hover event in CSS3 but I couldn't figure it out. Right now my picture is blurred 5px and I want it to be 0px of blur (essentially like using .focus() ) Can anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this?

with JQuery

```
$(function(){
   $('img').mouseover(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).css({
                        'filter': 'blur(0px)',
                        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(0px)',
                        '-moz-filter': 'blur(0px)',
                        '-o-filter': 'blur(0px)',
                        '-ms-filter': 'blur(0px)'
                    });

   }).mouseout(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).css({
                        'filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-moz-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-o-filter': 'blur(5px)',
                        '-ms-filter': 'blur(5px)'
                    });
   });
})
```

Pure CSS

```
img{
   filter: blur(5px),
   -webkit-filter: blur(5px),
   -moz-filter:blur(5px),
   -o-filter:blur(5px),
   -ms-filter:blur(5px)
}

img:hover{
   filter: blur(0px),
   -webkit-filter: blur(0px),
   -moz-filter:blur(0px),
   -o-filter:blur(0px),
   -ms-filter:blur(0px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image embedded in a hyperlink, you may have something that looks like:

```
<a href="http://someaddress.com/subsite/" class="blur"><img src="http://someaddress.com/images/image1.png"></a>
```

If you want to give CSS another try, you should be able to do the following:

```
a.blur img {
    filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -o-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
}

a.blur:hover img {
    filter: blur(0);
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    -moz-filter: blur(0);
    -o-filter: blur(0);
    -ms-filter: blur(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the mouseover state is called `hover`. You can [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to know how jQuery handle it.

For your code you can try this:

```
$('img').hover(function (event) {
   $(this).css({
      'filter': 'blur(0px)',
      '-webkit-filter': 'blur(0px)',
      '-moz-filter': 'blur(0px)',
      '-o-filter': 'blur(0px)',
      '-ms-filter': 'blur(0px)'
  });

}, function (event) {
   $(this).css({
        'filter': 'blur(5px)',
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur(5px)',
        '-moz-filter': 'blur(5px)',
        '-o-filter': 'blur(5px)',
        '-ms-filter': 'blur(5px)'
    });
});
```

This kind of events is better (and easier) to [handle with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), you can even add transition for them.

```
img {
  filter: blur(5px);
  webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter': blur(5px);
}

img:hover {
  filter: blur(0px);
  webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  -moz-filter: blur(0px);
  -o-filter: blur(0px);
  -ms-filter': blur(0px);
}
```

As a note, the `blur` function in jQuery correspond to [something else](https://api.jquery.com/blur/).